# Getting error while importing grid from ag-grid-enterprise

Tags: ag-grid

I am getting ../ag-grid-enterprise/main has no exported member grid/grid-options.

`import { Grid, GridOptions } from "ag-grid-enterprise";`

I have installed ag-grid-enterprise version and already mentioned license key

Answer (score 1):

Module `ag-grid-enterprise` does not have these members.

`GridOptions` exist in other module.

try next import:

`import { GridOptions } from '@ag-grid-community/core';`

ps: v.23

Comment: Please mark answer like correct if it helps you) thank you